# Who designed the first Apple Iphone and which design principles were followed in that?

Tags: iphone

Iphone was a very innovative product at that time introducing touch screen on a mobile phone. I wonder who was the designer on this one and which design principles were used in this process.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about history rather than UX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jonathan Ive, Steve Jobs, and the Apple Design Team

Jonathan Ive is influenced by the German designer, Dieter Rams: 
"Good design is innovative. 
Good design must be useful. 
Good design is aesthetic design. 
Good design makes a product understandable. 
Good design is honest. 
Good design is unobtrusive. 
Good design is long-lasting. 
Good design is consistent in every detail. 
Good design is environmentally friendly. 
And last but not least, good design is as little design as possible." 
– (The Ten points of Good Design – Dieter Rams)”